# Why can't I have operator associativity with precedence in Antlr v4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm using antlr v4 (eliminates direct left recursion).

My grammar's non-terminals are: `and`, `or`, `id`.

`and` has higher priority than `or`, and both of them are left associative.
According to Antlr4 reference if I put `and` before `or` it will have higher precedence.

So I have written this simple grammar:

```
expr : 'id'
     | expr BINOP expr
     ;

BINOP: 'and'<assoc=left>    //higher precedence
     | 'or'<assoc=left>     //lower precedence
     ;
```

But when it parses the string `id and id or id and id` the associativity is ok but
precedence is not ok: `((id and id) or id) and id`.

If I turn `BINOP` into a parser rule:

```
binop: 'and'<assoc=left>
     | 'or'<assoc=left>
     ;
```

neither associativity nor precedence work correctly:
`id and (id or (id and id))`

However when I implement `BINOP` inside expr parser rule:

```
expr : 'id'
     | expr 'and'<assoc=left> expr
     | expr 'or'<assoc=left> expr
     ;
```

everything works fine and I get the desired parse tree:
`(id and id) or (id and id)`

I googled a lot about the problem but I couldn't find anything.

I would be very glad if anyone could tell me where the problem is, and how
can I get correct associativity and precedence by having a separate rule for `BINOP`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The assoc=left is default so does nothing here. Also, precedence works on alternative level and you have put both operators at the same level:

expr BINOP expr

Ter

Comment: based on your answer I'm assuming that precedence does not work for different levels in lexer rules. Then why when I turn binop into a parser rule (as mentioned in the question) neither precedence nor associativity work correctly. And What is the right way to have precedence for a separate parser rule like binop. I really appreciate your time.